# MySQL query with WHERE subquery does not work on no result

Tags: mysql

I have written a complex query in MySQL to return a result. 
it works perfectly 

Until ..... 

the subquery returns no result 
how to write an if or IF null then substitute in date '2020-06-03'

any help greatly appreciated

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    trades 
WHERE
    stock_code = 'IHVV' 
    AND acc_id = '4' 
    AND tx_date > 
    (SELECT tx_date 
    FROM
        ( SELECT *, ( @sum_units := @sum_units + units ) AS sum_units 
        FROM
            trades
            JOIN ( SELECT @sum_units := 0 ) params 
        WHERE
            stock_code = 'IHVV' 
            AND acc_id = '4' 
            AND tx_date <= '2021-06-30' 
            AND ( transfer_date IS NULL OR transfer_date <= '2021-06-30' ) 
        ORDER BY
            tx_date ASC,
            units ASC 
        ) AS query1 
    WHERE
        tx_date < DATE_SUB( '2021-06-30', INTERVAL 1 YEAR ) 
        AND sum_units = 0 
    ORDER BY
        tx_date DESC 
        LIMIT 1 
    ) 
    AND tx_date <= '2021-06-30' 
    AND ( transfer_date IS NULL OR transfer_date <= '2021-06-30' ) 
ORDER BY
    tx_date ASC,
    units ASC
```

clarification 
I have written a main query and in one of the where clauses I am using a subquery  and this subquery works well, until this subquery does not return a result and my main query stops working, so I would like to on no result in this subquery substitute a value on no result so the main query can function normally

example needed
select * from table where date > (ifnull(subquery, "2002-01-01"))

I get
incorrect parameter count in the call to native function "IFNULL'

Comment: Your exact question is unclear to me, but maybe it helps you to know that you can use coalesce to replace null values by other values? As example anything like "WHERE COALESCE(transfer_date, GETDATE()) -1 <= GETDATE()"

Comment: I have written a main query and in one of the where clauses I am using a subquery  and this subquery works well, until this subquery does not return a result and my main query stops working, so I would like to on no result in this subquery of the where substitute a value on no result

Comment: *example needed: `where date > (ifnull(subquery, "2002-01-01"))`* This construction will fail if the subquery returns more than one row. You must limit the amount of rows returned (add LIMIT 1 with proper ordering). Also the output list of the subquery must contain one column only - if more then the query will fail again. PS. The subquery must be enclosed with parenthesis: `where date > (ifnull( (subquery) , "2002-01-01"))`

Comment: its limited to limit 1 but when it returns no result it fails

Comment: we need something like - > where does not exist then echo '2002-01-01'

Answer (score 0):

AND THE ANSWER IS: ---> :) 
thanks guys for all your suggestions 
much appreciated

```
SELECT *
        FROM trades 
        WHERE stock_code = 'IHVV' 
        AND acc_id = '4'
        AND tx_date > 
                    #last 0 date out of 1 year perhaps change the date range by from date and to date in the interval 1 year area
                (SELECT COALESCE(
                (SELECT tx_date 
                    FROM    (SELECT *, (@sum_units := @sum_units + units) AS sum_units  
                            FROM trades 
                            JOIN ( SELECT @sum_units := 0 ) params 
                            WHERE stock_code = 'ANZ' 
                                    AND acc_id = '4' 
                                    AND tx_date <= '2022-06-30' 
                                    AND (transfer_date IS NULL OR transfer_date <= '2022-06-30' ))
                            ORDER BY tx_date ASC, units ASC) as query1
                WHERE tx_date < DATE_SUB('2022-06-30',INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
                        AND sum_units = 0
                ORDER BY tx_date DESC
                LIMIT 1), 'TODATE')         
        
            AND tx_date <= '2022-06-30' 
            AND (transfer_date IS NULL OR transfer_date <= '2022-06-30' )
    ORDER BY tx_date ASC, units ASC
```